# Swapping VC's in a Container View - childVC does not fit Container

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

Latest Swift/XCode/iOS.

OK, I am trying to get my head around swapping out Child VC's in a Container View. I have read several posts describing how to do it, and they have been very helpful. However, I seem to be having a constraints issue that I can figure out.

I have a Master VC that contains some Container Views. The one Container contains several buttons (acting like a tab bar). When you tap on a button, the view controller in another "Detail" Container changes Child VC's. Code below:

```
    @IBAction func ToBioPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //SET RIGHT PANE VIEW TO BIO PAGE

    //INSTANTIATE NEW VC
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Biography")

    //REMOVE OLD VC
    detailPaneVCReference?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    detailPaneVCReference?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    detailPaneVCReference?.removeFromParentViewController()

    //ADD NEW VC
    ParentVC?.addChildViewController(vc!)
    vc?.view.frame = (detailContainerView?.bounds)!
    detailContainerView?.addSubview((vc?.view)!)


    //ADD CONSTRAINTS

    //TOP ANCHOR
    vc?.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.superview?.topAnchor)!).isActive = true

    //BOTTOM ANCHOR
    vc?.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.superview?.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true

    //LEADING ANCHOR
    vc?.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.superview?.leadingAnchor)!).isActive = true

    //TRAILING ANCHOR
    vc?.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (vc?.view.superview?.trailingAnchor)!).isActive = true


    vc?.didMove(toParentViewController: ParentVC)


}
```

The VC's of the Detail Container swap out but I cannot get the new one to fit completely. The Child VC runs past the bottom and right sides of the screen. The presence of the constraints added above do not even seem to make a difference. I get the same result whether they are there or not. I was expecting the frame = bounds line of code to ensure that the child fit completely within the Detail Container.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

**Edit**: Sorry, I forgot to mention that "detailPaneVCReference" is a reference to the starting VC within the Container View, grabbed during the embed segue. "detailContainerView" is a reference to the Container View itself, also grabbed during the embed segue. "ParentVC" is a reference to the MasterVC grabbed in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK crisis over. Turns out I was designing in storyboard for a 12 inch iPad and running as a 9.7 inch iPad. Several views had fixed value heights/widths - hence the wonky appearance when running the app.